# Удаление элемента в динамическом массиве. Очищение памяти

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, case

Программа удаляет элемент массива и выводит получившийся массив. Работает правильно, если выводить массив в том же кейсе, где и удаляешь элемент, но если запросить вывод в отдельном кейсе, то происходят проблемы с памятью.Предполагаю, что уменьшая size в одном кейсе, он не уменьшается в другом и при выводе программа залезает не в ту память. Вопрос почему?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{srand(2);
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    int size = 0;
    int* pr = &size;

    double* arr = new double[size];
    do
    {
        cout << "1 - создать, 2 - вывести, 3 - удалить " << endl;
        int choice;
        cin >> choice;
        if (size == 0)
        {
            cout << "Введите размер массива" << endl;
            cin >> size;
        }
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = rand() % 100;
            }
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < *pr; i++)
            {
                cout << i << ") " << (double)arr[i] << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            int index;
            cout << "Введите индекс элемента, который хотите удалить: " << endl;
            cin >> index;
            //index++;

            if (index <= size)
            {

                double* temp = new double[size];
                for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) temp[i] = arr[i];
                //delete[] arr;
                arr = new double[size - 1];
                for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; ++i, ++j)
                    if (i != index) arr[j] = temp[i];
                    else --j;
                *pr = *pr-1;
                for (int i = 0; i < *pr; i++)
                {
                    cout << i << ") " << (double)arr[i] << endl;
                }
                delete[index]arr;
                delete[] temp;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    delete[]arr;
}
```

Comment: Что это вообще такое: `delete[index]arr;`??? И зачем вы уничтожаете `arr`, который вы только что создали? Неудивительно, что программа не работает - вы же сами уничтожили свой `arr`.

Comment: `(double)arr[i]` - зачем вы делаете эти приведения типа, когда `arr[i]` и так `double`?

Comment: delete[index]arr мне подсказали, сам я тоже впервые использую такой синтаксис, но он работает как нужно. arr я уничтожаю правильно, после всего цикла

Comment: Я не знаю, кто вам такое "подсказал", но это полнейшая и дичайшая чушь. Нет, в С++ в принципе нет такого синтаксиса. И нет, он не "работает как нужно". Вам показалось. Ваш этот `delete[index] arr` (если "дырявый" компилятор это пропустил) просто эквивалентно `delete[] arr`, т.е. тупо убивает весь массив, который вы создавали. Поэтому все и падает.